# Override a Scala function that needs a classTag

Tags: scala

```
  implicit val instance = new Functor[SomeDataType] {
    override def map[A, B](fa: SomeDataType[A])(f: A => B): SomeDataType[B] =  {

      val newGrid: Array[B] = Array.ofDim[B](100)
      // ...
    }
  }
```

In the code above it won't compile because to create an array I need a classTag for the type B. Unfortunately if I create a type bounds of type ClassTag then that changes the function signature and my override will no longer be an override. Same problem if I use an implicit parameter.

Is there a way to create the Array of type B and still override the parent function?

Comment: No, if I understand your requirements correctly there isn't. Try to find a way to avoid creating an `Array[B]`, e.g. by using an `Array[Object]` and casting explicitly when needed (note: that's how Java handles `T[]` without an equivalent to `ClassTag`).

Comment: If you are on `2.13` you can use **ArraySeq** which has some untagged versions _(and it is also immutable)_.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks I'll look into that

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yeah that might be possible, I was thinking of using reflection on an instance of B to get the tag but that felt pretty hacky